# Persistence property of File in typo3

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to set deleted() property of TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File and make it actually permanent saving that property on the database.
I need to update my FileReference but is not working, is adding a new image to my record.

So I do:

```
$fileReference->getOriginalFile()->setDeleted(true);
```

But then? How is possible to save that into the sys_file table? There is a TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileRepository but it doesn't have an update() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `delete()` function on `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File`:

```
$fileReference->getOriginalFile()->delete();
```

`setDeleted()` is used internally and is not meant to be public API.

Comment: I think that works. How can I call the filereferences of a record? With findByRelation? I don't understand the parameters of that one.

Comment: The easiest way depends on the context where you want to get it. Usually with TCA:inline you get FileReferences in Extbase models or via Fluid DataProcessors.

Comment: I'm doing this on the frontend with a controller. When I update my record with a new file from my form in a fulid template, the file doesn't get updated, it add's this file to the record and now my record has two files (I can go to the backend, check this record, and both file are there). But when I get a model of this record I'm just getting the first file, not both. I don't understand well how the upload file is working that's why I'm working around this.

Comment: So because when I update my record it works fine but I end up with two files saved instead of just one, (the new one) is that I want to call this both (or more) file and delete the one I don't need. But $this->entitiyRepository() gives me a model with just the first file, no signal of the rest.

Comment: If my answer helped, please accept it. If you want to ask a new question, please do so and provide more context and code.

Comment: Yes, there are contexts hard to give so questions hard to ask. No, it doesn't help me but I guess is still the right answer. Thanks anyways.